# How do I install elementary os with DVD on a iBookG4 Powerbook 6,7 with PowerPC?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

I'm having trouble with installing Freya on an iBookG4/PowerBook 6,7 with a PowerPC processor.

When I restart with the DVD install disk, the boot screen shows only the hard drive.

I used the disk utility to burn the disk image of the .iso to a DVD.  Press the OPTION button after the chime.  The boot screen appears, with only the hard drive to select.

Is Freya/installation compatible with PowerPC processor?

I've also tried a Luna download, burned to a CD, with the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You can't install Elementary OS on a PowerPC Mac. Elementary OS is for Intel architecture only. For PowerPC Macs you can install Ubuntu for PowerPC:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads

or another distro for PowerPC